# iOs - error with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, date-format

I have a Date with value `2015-05-31 22:00:00 UTC` (I parse it from a NSString with value `"01-06-2015"` and it give that value) and when I parse it it become `01-06` why??

I need to get on nextdate the value =  `2015-06-1 22:00:00 UTC` because I need to get the day of the week

Code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];

NSDate *nextDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:comps2 toDate:date2 options:0];

NSString* primeraFecha = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
```

Values at runtime

[image]

Comment: did you set the time zone for the formatter?

Comment: nope, how I can do it?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what `comps2` and `date2` are set to?

Comment: yes but comps2 was good, the problem was the timezone as answers said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:@"Europe/London"]];
return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the time zone of your formatter:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```